# How many 3 letters-long codes can be made by 5 different letters?

Tags: combinatorics

You have five letters: C, H, E, S, T

How many different codes, consisting of three letters, can be made from the above letters?

I'd say ${5}\choose{3}$ is the correct answer, since the order of the letters doesn't matter. Is this (that the order doesn't matter) why $\frac{5!}{3!}$ isn't the correct answer?

Comment: Can you repeat letters?

Comment: You don't think that 'CHE' and 'HEC' should be separate codes?

Comment: Well, CuddlyCuttlefish, when you put it like that... It seems more reasonable that $\frac{5!}{3!}$ is the correct answer, cause then you won't get codes like that... Correct? :)

Comment: The order of the letters does matter. Assuming that we cannot repeat letters, we have $^5\mathrm{P}_3=\frac{5!}{2!}=60$ different codes. If we can repeat letters, then there are $5^3$ different codes.

Comment: I would say $5^3$, if you can repeat letters.

Comment: @YinonEliraz, thanks. :)

Comment: Why do you say the order doesn't matter? I've never seen a code where the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of interpretation, you can arrive at the answer using the [Multiplication Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

> If a every outcome can be uniquely described via a sequence of answers to questions with number of choices $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots$ respectively where regardless of *which* choice is made the number of available choices doesn't change, then the total number of outcomes will be $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3\cdots$

---

If letters are allowed to be repeated and order does matter:

Pick the first letter (5 choices), pick the second letter (5 choices), pick the third letter (5 choices), for a total of $5^3$ different codes.

---

If letters are not allowed to be repeated and order does matter:

Pick the first letter (5 choices), pick the second letter (4 remaining choices), pick the third letter (3 remaining choices), for a total of $5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = \frac{5!}{2!}$ different codes.

---

If letters are allowed to be repeated and order doesn't matter:

Apply [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to get that there will be $\binom{3+5-1}{5-1}$ different codes.

---

If letters are not allowed to be repeated and order doesn't matter:

Standard combinations problem: there are $\binom{5}{3}$ such choices.  (Provable via a multiplication principle + division by amount of symmetry argument).

Answer (score 0):

Letters can be repeated. The first letter can be chosen from 5 different letters, so can the second and third letter. Thus the answer is $5^{3} = 125$ different codes.

Thank you @Yinon Eliraz!